# Python Pandas number regex for part number

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype='unicode')

df.dropna(subset=["Description.1"], inplace = True)

df_filtered = df[(df['Part'].str.contains("-")==True) & (df['Part'].str.len()==8)]
```

I am trying to get python pandas to only filter in the Part column to show numbers in this format: "###-####"

I cannot seem to figure out how to only show those. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now, I have it where it filters part numbers with a '-' in them, and where the length is 8 digits long. Even with this, I am still getting some that aren't the correct format to our internal format.

Can't seem to find anything similar to this online, and I am fairly new to Python.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""name,dig
aaa,750-2220
bbb,12-214
ccc,120
ddd,1020-10"""))

df.loc[df.dig.str.contains(r"\d{3}-\d{4}")]
```

which outputs

```
  name       dig
0  aaa  750-2220
```